# How to mount NAS drive to Linux server?

Tags: network-attached-storage

I have a qnap ts-419p+, according to its manual, I need to setup the NAS through a browser. Now, I have a CentOS server(no GUI), how do I mount the NAS drive to this Linux server? I only want to use the NAS as a storage. I've connected the NAS with the CentOS server with LAN, but I don't know how to find the NAS in CentOS server. Thanks.

Comment: What protocols have you enabled on the NAS?

Comment: I didn't do anything on NAS yet. If I need to enable any protocols, do I need another computer with GUI to setup first, then connect NAS to the Linux server(without GUI)?

Comment: Jefferson has provided the answers below, you need to enable SMB/iSCSI to be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this page, http://www.qnap.com/pro_detail_feature.asp?p_id=183, your NAS have both SMB and iSCSI shares.

If SMB share is enabled, you should use the mount command:

mount.cifs //IP or NAS NetBiosname/PATH/TO/NAS/ /mountpoint -o user=User pass=password dom=Domain

If iSCSI is enabled, you should try this:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-iscsi-howto.html